# When expressing opinions : to me vs for me

Tags: grammar

What is correct?: "To me, studying is important" or " For me, studying is important"

Answer (score 0):

"To me, studying is important." Is correct in a grammatical sense. "For me and only me, studying is important." Would be more possessive than opinion.

Comment: The " more possessive part" I didn't quite get it...

Comment: Would mean you are taking ownership of your position of opinion.

Comment: By the way .. Is there a chance to chat via Skype or other means 'cause I'm an English language teacher and I have doubts all the time, besides I'm a native Spanish speaker if anybody is interested that would be great (Only in a professional sense)

Comment: That would be against the rules.